# Perforce Revision of Files

Tags: perforce, overwrite

Cannot over write files on Perforce

A file with errors was uploaded to Perforce, we are now trying to overwrite that file and update it with the correct file. Unfortunately many of the character assets will not resolve showing a padlock, yellow triangle and a red tick.

The error messages are telling us that we can't overwrite the files unless we have an up to date version. The most up to date version is the one with errors! How do we unlock and resolve these assets

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest revisions. You can browse submitted changelists and identify a changelist that introduces the error. You can back out that changelist which will create changelist on which the files will be edited that way that their content will be reverted. Submit that changelist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which UI you're using (P4V?  P4Win?  One of the IDE plugins?), so I'll just give the command line instructions:

```
p4 sync FILE
p4 resolve -ay
```

The `sync` tells Perforce that you want to sync up with the latest depot revision of the file.  Since the file is open for edit, this won't actually modify the file on disk, and will instead set up a resolve operation.

The `resolve -ay` (accept yours) tells Perforce that you want to ignore the latest revision from the depot, and keep **your** workspace revision instead, which is the one that you want to submit.

Now the "yellow triangle" should go away and you'll be able to submit.  (Unless that "padlock" belongs to someone else...)